Practicing smartphone gestures in safe environment directly on Android for non-techy users
I have an aging parent who I want to acquaint with using an Android smartphone. Gestures are a bit of a problem for him, and I want to acquaint him with swipe-down, swipe right, long-press, single tap, double tap, pinch zoom. Preferably but not necessarily in the context of actual Android phone use - bringing down settings, moving a shortcut around on the desktop, moving a shortcut to another page on the desktop, etc.
Is there a way to achieve this? In the context of actual use (i.e. practice on a 'practice desktop' where nothing he does is permanent. Or something simpler just for practice would do. I'd just give him a smartphone to practice on, but he lives a long distance away and it's difficult to tell if and when he screws a gesture up and does something inadvertently or changes some setting that leads to headaches.
